# Dell precision 7510 fails to suspend: xhci_hcd timeout

Tags: suspend, dell, xhci-hcd

My Dell Precision 7510 with Ubuntu 17.10 will often fail to suspend.
Warning messages are displayed, then the login screen comes back.

`dmesg` gives:

```
thermal thermal_zone10: failed to read out thermal zone (-5)
[26797.500002] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[26797.502461] PM: Preparing system for sleep (freeze)
[26797.552411] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[26797.554190] OOM killer disabled.
[26797.554190] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[26797.555319] PM: Suspending system (freeze)
[26797.555320] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[26797.555526] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: WARN: xHC CMD_RUN timeout
[26797.555530] suspend_common(): xhci_pci_suspend+0x0/0xd0 returns -110
[26797.555532] pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -110
[26797.555535] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x130 returns -110
[26797.555536] PM: Device 0000:3c:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -110
[26798.055512] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: Ignoring mailbox command error (-110) in icm_suspend
[26798.055645] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[26798.055740] PM: resume of devices complete after 0.092 msecs
[26818.437218] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[26818.437219] OOM killer enabled.
[26818.437221] Restarting tasks ... done.
```

I tried a solution from this site (can't find it back) where I added a script in `/etc/pm/config.d/` with `SUSPEND_MODULES=xhci_hcd` but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: Here is the info from `lshw` about that device:

```
*-generic:4
    description: Unassigned class
    product: Illegal Vendor ID
    vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
    physical id: 5
    bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
    version: ff
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 66MHz
    capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list
    configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=255 maxlatency=255 mingnt=255
    resources: irq:138 memory:d9f00000-d9f0ffff
*-usbhost:0
        product: xHCI Host Controller
        vendor: Linux 4.13.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
        physical id: 0
        bus info: usb@3
        logical name: usb3
        version: 4.13
        capabilities: usb-2.00
        configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
*-usbhost:1
        product: xHCI Host Controller
        vendor: Linux 4.13.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
        physical id: 1
        bus info: usb@4
        logical name: usb4
        version: 4.13
        capabilities: usb-3.10
        configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying to better understand the failing device (`Device 0000:3c:00.0`) with a `lshw` and `grep` for that device. That should be useful information.

Comment: @richbl `3c:00.0` doesn't appear in `lshw` for the moment but the laptop can sleep. I'll see if it appears when the laptop fails to sleep...

Comment: @richbl It is happening again now and I have added the `lshw` info to the question